# Сохранение данных в ios

Tags: xcode, ios

Только начал изучать разработку под ios ( до этого занимался web прогр.). Например я хочу сделать мультиязычное приложение. Пользователь выбирает в настройках язык (настройки сохраняются), после этого меняется язык в приложении на нужный.

- **Первый вопрос**: после того как пользователь изменит настройки, как и куда можно их сохранять? Есть ли возможность работать с базой данных? (дайте хотя бы напутствие, чтобы было что загуглить).
- **Второй вопрос**: где нужно хранить языки приложения, чтобы потом их выбирать и вставлять в контент. (думаю массив не самое удачное место).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial Посмотрите этот туториал, довольно доступно все описано

Answer (score 1):

Давайте по порядку:

1. В iOs нет такого понятия как выбранная локализация приложения, приложение подцепляет ту локализацию, на которое настроено устройство (в настройках-стандартные-язык), делать свой велосипед с выбором локали будет неправильно. Ссылку как добавить локализацию чтобы ее подцепило приложение уже дал выше [@AlexThumb](/users/7983/alexthumb)
2. За работу с настройками в iOs отвечает класс [NSUserDefaults](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/), при желании туда даже можно будет запустить свои кастомные классы, упаковав их через NSKeyedArchiver.
3. По базам данных - можно спокойно работать с sqlite, взаимодействие через его С-апи входит в стандартный сдк, но здесь он вам не нужен